# How do you cite song lyrics parenthetically in MLA?

Tags: citations, mla, lyrics

I am in the process of finishing up a research paper for school that I am writing on the debate over whether or not you should listen to an album from start to finish. I am specifically doing so with respect to Pink Floyd's The Dark Side of the Moon. As a result, I cite song lyrics several times throughout my paper. I have been looking online for guidelines as far as how to cite these lyrics parenthetically in MLA. I have seen people suggesting (Band name), (Songwriter Line Numbers), and (Songwriter). I was wondering if someone could please enlighten me as to which of these (if any) are the correct method of doing so. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!
EDIT: Also would appreciate guidance for the works cited page in addition to parenthetical! I have been searching on the internet and am confused as to whether I just cite the songwriter, songwriter and band, or just the band and how I would do so for the bibliography

Comment: Didn't want to bump again, but also, would I distinguish the separate songs in the parentheticals as well? I guess I would have to since all of the songs were written by the same writer. If someone could show me how that would be done, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

MLA format of song lyrics goes like this:

**NOTE: Usage of [] indicates information which should be included only if applicable.**

Lyricist last name, Lyricist first name. Lyrics used in the paper. "Title of Song". Album name. Medium for music (CD, MP3, cassette, etc...). Record company name. Year of release. [Name of website where lyrics were sourced from, Date of access, Lyric Webpage URL].

I hope this helped!
[Source](http://penandthepad.com/cite-song-lyrics-mla-format-4180.html)